# Saltstack running a bash script through cmd.script via rest_cherrypy with multiple args

Tags: salt-stack

Trying to use rest_cherrypy to run a bash script on minion. Script takes multiple args. In the following example it works fine with one argument:

```
 resp = session.post('https://192.168.50.10:8000/', json=[{    
      'client': 'local',                                        
      'tgt': 'minion1',                                         
      'fun': 'cmd.script',                                      
      'arg': ['salt://scripts/my_script.sh', 'arg1'],           
  }])                                                           
  return resp.json()
```

Output: `{'return': [{'minion1': {'pid': 2836, 'retcode': 0, 'stderr': '', 'stdout': 'arg1'}}]}`

However trying to use multiple arguments gives me this:

```
 resp = session.post('https://192.168.50.10:8000/', json=[{
        'client': 'local',
        'tgt': 'minion1',
        'fun': 'cmd.script',
        'arg': ['salt://scripts/my_script.sh', ('arg1', 'arg2')],
    }])
    return resp.json()
```

Output:

```
{'return': [{'minion1': {'pid': 2808, 'retcode': 0, 'stderr': '', 'stdout': '[uarg1,'}}]}
```

What's the correct way to pass multiple arguments to a cmd.script function through rest_cherrypy?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it this way:

```
    resp = session.post('https://192.168.50.10:8000/', json=[{                                                        
     'client': 'local',                                                                                            
     'tgt': 'minion1',                                                                                             
     'fun': 'cmd.script',                                                                                          
     'arg': ['salt://scripts/my_script.sh', """ {}, {}, {}, {} """.format(mail_from, mail_to, date_from, date_to)],
 }])
```